# Why no null pointer exception will be thrown

Tags: java

Following is the code snippet:

```
class A {
  static void staticMethod() {
    System.out.println("Static Method");
  }
}


public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = null;

    a.staticMethod();
  }
}
```

When `A a = null` means `a` is `null`. Then why a.staticMethod() doesn't throw `Null Pointer`?

Comment: This is because the method is static read up about static methods

Answer (score 5):

Because `staticMethod` is `static`, so the compiler replaces `a.staticMethod();` with `A.staticMethod();`

Answer (score 1):

Quoth the JLS ([§15.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4). *Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation*):

> If form is *ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier*, then:
>
> If the invocation mode is `static`, then there is no target reference. The *ExpressionName* is evaluated, but the result is then discarded.
>
> Otherwise, the target reference is the value denoted by *ExpressionName*.

And:

> If the invocation mode is `static`, no target reference is needed and overriding is not allowed. Method `m` of class `T` is the one to be invoked.
>
> Otherwise, an instance method is to be invoked and there is a target reference. If the target reference is `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown at this point.

So, a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the method is not static and the "target reference" is `null`; but for a static method there is no "target reference", and no null-check is performed.

It would have been possible for the JLS to specify a null-check here, but it does not, so there isn't one. Personally I think it would have made more sense to forbid expressions like `a.staticMethod()` where `a` is a variable instead of the class, but for better or worse, the Java language designers chose to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Because static methods belong to classes, they do not belong to instances of classe

Answer (score 0):

Because of static method, all the static members are resolved at compile time.